# Query CDF of discrete distribution at arbitrary points in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, probability-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a discrete distribution say `x=[1,2,4,5]; P(x)=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`. CDF is given by `F(x)=[0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1]`. Here the `P` and `F` arrays denote the corresponding values at the given `x`. In my case, `P` is not actually a discrete distribution, but piecewise uniform with support `x \in [1, 9]` i.e. for `x \in [1, 2], P(x)=0.1; x \in [2, 4], P(x)=0.1; x \in [4, 5], P(x)=0.3; x \in [5,9], P(x)=0.1`
I want to query the CDF of this distribution at different points, say `y=[0.5, 1.6, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.7, 8.9]`. Now `F(y)=[0, 0.06, 0.13, 0.24, 0.45, 0.67, 0.99]`. Is there a way (some library function) to get `F(y)` quickly without having to compute it manually?

In my case, `x` and `P` are array of the list of values (2D array) of shape `(batch_size, num_bins)` and `y` is also a 2D array of shape `(batch_size, num_new_bins)`. I want to compute this efficiently in PyTorch and this should allow gradient backprop as well.